# Laravel 5 (Validate only submitted fields)

Tags: laravel-5

I am developing a Laravel 5.2 app using ajax for form submissions.

I am using this plugin, to divide a big form into steps. http://www.panopta.com/2013/02/06/bootstrap-application-wizard-2/#validation

It's possible to trigger a specific validation function per card.

Here's what I am trying to do, when the first card's validation function is called, I would like to make an ajax request to Laravel, but only validate the fields submitted on the first card, if it validates, it must return true and continue to the next card.

Problem is that Laravel is expecting all the fields to be present when validating, how can I only validate the fields that are submitted on card validation.

Once wizard gets to the end, I can safely assume all the data is ready for submission.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand what you're trying to do, but:

using `->sometimes` you can validate based on a conditional statement.

```
$v->sometimes('reason', 'required|max:500', function($input) {
    return $input->games >= 100;
});
```

Read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules).

Comment: That's the perfect answer, exactly what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you.